# How to get Original image URL in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-images

I need to create a link of an image that should not be resized by magento2.That original image should be cached.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below function to get the Media base url :

```
function getMediaBaseUrl() {

$om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$storeManager = $om->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');

$currentStore = $storeManager->getStore();
return $currentStore->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
}
```

Using getMediaBaseUrl() function we can find image url in Magento2:

```
echo $this->getMediaBaseUrl() .'catalog/product'. $_product->getImage();
```

Comment: is this for current product?

Comment: $_product->getImage() is for any product

Comment: but i need image like this one http://prntscr.com/nr9a2l

Comment: please attach code..

Comment: which code....?

Comment: you try any code for get original path for product image ???

Comment: ok let me try then i will share it with you .

Comment: or attach code which exctly you get image original path

Comment: @RkRathod, can we replace this product image in list page, instead of loading the image $block->getImage($_product, $image);

Comment: i m not sure bro